# Django One to many field..........?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hey friend i am competely new in django models .
My question is, i have five table attributes like .

```
Rulno (integer)
From (IpAddressfield )
To(IpAddressfield )
Priority (integer)
Cisp(CharField)
```

Their can be many number of  Priority and Cisp for a single Ruleno .so for i am writing model like .

```
class Ruleinfo(models.Model):
    rule = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    From = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    to = models.IPAddressField(null=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey('Priority',related_name = 'priority1')
    Cisp =models.ForeignKey('Priority',related_name = 'cisp1')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.rule)



class Priority(models.Model):  
    priority =  models.IntegerField(null = True)
    Ruleno = models.ForeignKey('Ruleinfo')
    CISP = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s ' % (self.priority)
```

i am wondering, above model will fulfill my requirement or not ? .

or do let me know if any alternative is there .?

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to do it is with a `ForeignKey` on the other end of the relation.

Comment: Just an addition: You should lower-case your model fields for consistency and readability.

Comment: This breaks when you have an abstract model1, model2 with a foreign key in model2. When you subclass these models, you have to explicitly add the foreign key in model2_subclass. This is acceptable. But if I have code written using abstract classes then I can't traverse a many_to_one relation using model1_obj.foreignkeyfield but I cannot traverse a one-to-many field  in a generic way. I cannot do model2_obj.model1_field_set.all().

Comment: well I take that back ... there is related_name and abstract naming that I did not know about.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name